# Discord.py get guild.id before ctx

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make the command cooldown be a variable taken from the server json file. But how do I access that file when I can't get the guild.id before ctx. Is it even possible to set the cooldown like this?

```py
@misc.command(name="databasetest", description="Testing the databases.")
guild_id = ctx.guild.id
with open(f'/home/container/theulenium/servers/{guild_id}/server.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

    workcooldown = data[0].get('work_cooldown')
@commands.cooldown(1, workcooldown, commands.BucketType.user)
async def databasetest(ctx):

    with open('/home/container/theulenium/encrypted_services/users.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    for user in data['users']:
        if user['user_name'] == 'Aywei':
            items = user['items']
            break

    for item in items:
        if item['name'].lower() == 'apple':
            item_name = item['name']
            item_description = item['description']
            item_worth = item['worth']
            item_amount = item['amount']
            break

    await ctx.send(f"Item Name: {item_name}, Item Description: {item_description}, Item Worth: {item_worth}. Item amount: {item_amount}", ephemeral=True)
```

I didn't try nothing than what is shown in the code. I don't know what should I do with this. I am expecting it that if the command is executed it will read the specific server.json for the work_cooldown variable and then apply it in the dsicord.cooldown